# angularjs seo phantomjs write the snapshots first or during the crawling

Tags: angularjs, seo, phantomjs

I'm wondering what's the best option to write
the snapshots (a snapshots is a plain html version of an angular state/route
built for bots for seo purpose)

- First (ie all the times an author user add a post in a blog)
- or during the crawling

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of -1

Comment: What do you mean with *first* and what are *snapshots*?

Comment: with first I mean adding a new post in a blog ie. Take a look at http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: Thanks, I wondered about that some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking there's no best option, there is the option that best fit for you.

It depends on your case: for example, if your content is dynamically generated (I mean content generated from users as blog or forums or whatever) you have to write your snapshots during the crawling, otherwise you could generate the snapshots before.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to go for *first* in every case, because firing up a phantomjs instance on the crawl is time costly and search engines (google) give a penalty for long loading time. It would be better to do generate the static page when new content is created.

If you have too many create events to run the *first* approach, you might consider ignoring some of them. For example, if you have a highly frequented blog with many comments, you could run the generation for every new blog post, but only run it for every 20 comments or every 10 minutes, whichever is earlier.